# Windows API global hook's unlimited range

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, keyboard-events

I'm trying to make a C++ application that handles keyboard events (actually, just want to "catch" some phrases the user types) on every application running on the PC. The very base of what I am trying to make is this :

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

HHOOK hHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    printf("Activated\n"); 
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, hInstance, 0);
  MSG msg;
  while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  return msg.wParam;
}
```

Now, this one is global, but still I got stuck when I found out that it doesn't "hear" my keyboard input when I run a specific application. From what I found the problem must be that the desired application does not belong to the same desktop as my application (since this callback function is global for my application's desktop). I tried to implement some desktop-switching tricks but I'm really not familiar with windows API and all my efforts soon failed. MSDN referal is not enough for a tutorial. Is there any way I can make my application able to catch keyboard input from EVERYWHERE on my computer ?

Thanks in advance for any help/tips !

Comment: These limitations are there to protect you (the user) from malicious applications (keyloggers and such). Not that they succeed so much...

Comment: Global hook in second desktop.

Comment: Applications cannot access desktops other than their own. You will need a copy of the application on each desktop, or use a driver. It's not clear why you need to hook other desktops. Maybe the person logged into the other desktop doesn't want your macro program. (Maybe that other person is an administrator who doesn't want you keylogging their activity.)

Comment: Actually all applications I'm interested in are executed by one user (me), so the problematic application possibly blocks hooks or does not "cooperate" directly with my desktop (no idea if this is even possible). Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global hook must be implemented in a DLL, so it can hook into multiple processes.  And you have to implement separate 32-bit and 64-bit versions if you want to support 64-bit systems.  The documentation for `SetWindowsHookEx()` says as much.

Instead of using a global hook, try using [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543.aspx) instead.  Use [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645600.aspx) to register interest in the keyboard, and then handle [`WM_INPUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645590.aspx) messages for the keystrokes.

Comment: Hmmm, handling the devices directly when they interact seems to be the way to go, thanks for your tips, I'll check it out definitely !

Comment: Uuum, any idea what I need to do in order to start using the Raw Input model ? I installed Microsoft Platform SDK and included the paths : "Microsoft Platform SDK\Lib" and "Microsoft Platform SDK\Include" on the respective Directories in my VC 2010 project, but I still get "undeclared Identifier" errors when using the Raw Input declarations.

Comment: Make sure your code is `#include`'ing `windows.h`, and your project is defining `_WIN32_WINNT` to `0x0501` or higher.

Comment: I just finished an implementation with Raw Input, unfortunately it doesn't work on the same application I had the problem with LowLevelKeyboardProc implementation. It was a nice way to handle events anyway, to solve my problem I ended up with using RegisterHotKey with combinations for every keyboard key I need (very brute method, with many disadvantages and possible previous hotkey replacements, not suggested if you don't need it, but at least it worked truely globally without being blocked by any application).

Just putting this line here for future reference to third party individuals.